# Java: How do I read a file as a set of bytes?

Tags: java, file, cryptography

I'm working on a program intended to read a file and encrypt it, and I was hoping to use Java to improve cross-platform compatibility. Is the a way to load the bytes that constitute a file into Java and store then as a variable, so that I could then run the algorithms on them? Or would there be a better way to read the for that I'm intending to encrypt/decrypt?

Comment: Googled 'encrypt file java': http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ml355/lore/pkencryption.htm ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read an entire InputStream into a byte[].

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

I would however recommend adapting your algorithms to work on the stream directly. Files can get very large so loading them entirely into memory can be expensive or impossible.